# How can dilation of a wavelet function lead to its sign reversal?

Tags: signal-analysis, wavelet

I am studying wavelets and it has been given that

$$
\psi_{a,b}  = \frac{1}{\sqrt{|a|}} \psi \left(\frac{t-b}{a}\right)
$$

now the function

$$
\psi(t)= 
\begin{cases}
    1,& \text{if } 0\leq t<\frac 12\\
    -1, & \text{if } \frac 12\leq t<1\\            
0& \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} 
$$

is given as in terms of previous equation

$$
\psi_{a,b}= \frac {1} {\sqrt{a}}\left[u(t-a)-2u\left(t-b-\frac a2\right)+u(t-b-a)\right]
$$

when $a>0$ and

$$
\psi_{a,b}=- \frac {1} {\sqrt{-a}}\left[u(t-a)-2u\left(t-b-\frac a2\right)+u(t-b-a)\right]
$$

when $a<0$.

My issue is, how can $a$ which is a dilation parameter lead to something like a negative function when $a<0$?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because verbatim copy of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2035548/how-can-dilation-parameter-a-in-wavelet-leads-to-sign-reversal without referring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, $\frac{t}{-a} =\frac{-t}{a}$.

Comment: Thanks!!! I got it. I was not able to do it graphically, but now I can.

Comment: Perfect, I was almost  confused of the short response. It is quite interested to look at the property in the Fourier domain: $\phi(at)\to \frac{1}{|a|}\Phi(f/a)$. You can see how the sign change  on $f$ due to $a=-1$ can transfer to $t$ in the $e^{-i2\pi ft}$, and you have to intervert the two $-\infty$ and $\infty$  bounds on the integral, hence the sign change.